# Creating a session without using cookie

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, session, jakarta-ee, cookies

I want to create application similar to faebook's "like". In Facebook, once you logged in Facebook, all the website with "like" plugin can access that facebook login and fetch necessary data(e.g. you have liked or not or how many your friends/people liked that page or whatever). But, to maintain session facebook uses cookies to store session on browser. 
If you close/delete cookie, it won't work.

Is there any technology or any approach to maintain session on server or not dependent on cookies?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I take you mean the Facebook "like" button on third-party websites?

This will call the Facebook service directly, using both their API, and loading an "instance" of the FB interface in an iframe.

--

**CORS**

The primary thing you're looking at is how to manage the [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) element of your service

**CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing)** allows external servers to access the resources on your server through Ajax. This is probably the most important element of the process, as it allows the likes of FB / Twitter to load the numeric "general" data for their buttons.

This is partly where you'll achieve your functionality, and is what the original answer was referring to when he recommended `*`

A Rails [gem called RACK-CORS](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors) handles CORS policies for Rails / Rack apps:

```
  #config/application.rb
  use Rack::Cors do
    allow do
      origins '*'
      resource '/buttons/*', :headers => :any, :methods => :get
    end
  end
```

When you use the JS below, you'll basically be able to send an Ajax request to `domain.com/buttons/:button_id` to get a pingback of the data (number of likes etc)

--

**JS**

The button itself will be populated with JS, and will likely call either JSON or plain HTTP to gain the generic data required

It will retrieve the number of "likes" from the Facebook service. This will be done with JS, and will require the CORS setup as mentioned above, as it will use [XHR](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp) to retrieve the required data.

This is why you need to have at least a page ID, and sometimes some sort of deeper authentication (app ID, widget ID, oAuth) to get one of these widgets on your site. Reason being that in order for the button to retrieve the required data, the server will need to know what the data is for

You could do something like this:

```
#javascript xhr
(function($){
   //call Ajax to get numeric data for button
});
```

--

**Authentication**

If you want to know if a user has "liked" a page, you'll be best using the method of both FB & Twitter (I think) and using an `iframe` to load the button

This might sound old-skool, but the fact is that an `iframe`, hosted on the FB service, will give you the ability to authenticate the session on the service itself, thus providing the ability to know if the button has been "activated" or not.

To answer your question directly, the button would not maintain the session; it will be within the remit of how the button is called (is it on the server?)

Comment: Thanks for quick Response ... I got what you said. But I am not getting my main concern to maintain or access session of user with no dependency on cookie (facebook and google doing same). If you disable your browser cookie none of them will even allow you to login.